# How to setup Ruby on Rails app without an ORM, using only low-level database driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arangodb

I want to create a Rails application using [ArangoDB.](https://www.arangodb.com/) It has Rails adapter, [Guacamole,](https://github.com/triAGENS/guacamole) but it doesn't have some features I'd like to have (namely, AQL). So I'm thinking of building my own models using low-level [Ashikawa](https://triagens.github.io/ashikawa-core/) driver.

What code do I need to write for this to function properly? I imagine I'll have to write an initializer to establish the connection, is there anything else that I'm missing?

Thank you.

Comment: I am one of the authors of both Ashikawa and Guacamole. It is not true that Guacamole does not support AQL. You can find all information [here](https://github.com/triAGENS/guacamole#experimental-aql-support). If that is not enough, take the answer of @papirtiger.

Comment: @moonglum I see, thank you. Can I use graph functions with it?

Comment: You're welcome! We are currently working on the next release which will be ready soon and support graphs :smile:

Comment: @moonglum Yay! I'll be waiting. I really like ArangoDB and I'd really love to see Guacamole fully embracing the power of AQL.

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generating a app with `rails new my_app -O` will give you an app without ActiveRecord. The [Mongoid Installation Guide](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/installation.html) has a step by step of how to get rid of ActiveRecord in an existing app.

I imagine that you would then establish a connection in an initialiser, and create either a model class that your models extend (in the style of ActiveRecord) or a mixin which your models include (ala Mongoid::Document). This module or class will house any shared functionality required.

You might want to extend `ActiveModel::Model` as it will give you inflection, validations and other features.

Comment: Agreed. I would suggest creating your own model class that inherits from `ActiveModel::Model` or parts of it and then gradually extending it.